# A question about conjunctions

Tags: word-order, conjunction

Conversion of verbs into question appearance (placing the verb at the start of the sentence) in a sentence when the conjunction is at the start of the sentence even though the conjunction is not subordinate but compound.

For example

> Entweder **bist** du Teil der Lösung, oder du bist Teil des Problems.

is how it is supposed to be but i thought that their place wouldn't change.

As the rule says it should be the same order as regular ones'.
It should be:

> Entweder du **bist** Teil der Lösung, oder du bist Teil des Problems.

Comment: Sehen wir hier eine Frage oder die Platzierung des Verbs am Satzanfang?

Answer (score 1):

*Entweder* is not a conjunction but an **adverb**. If an adverb takes the first position in a V2 sentence (i.e. in a main clause), per definition the verb follows on the second position and the other parts come thereafter. If you transform a standalone V2 sentence into an *entweder ... oder* sentence, the former part on position 1 (before the verb) is moved behind the verb that takes the second position.

Take this as an example for the basic principle of moving around the first part of a sentence in a V2 sentence:

> Ich **gehe** sonntags gerne spazieren.
>
> Sonntags **gehe** ich gerne spazieren

Now we make a similar sentence that features an alternative with *oder*:

> Ich **gehe** spazieren *oder* [ich] **schaue** mir einen Film an.

The second *ich* can be omited in the form of an ellipsis.

We will now see that *entweder* is a normal adverb and can be shifted around like *sonntags* in the example above:

> Ich **gehe** entweder spazieren *oder* [ich] **schaue** mir einen Film an.
>
> Entweder **gehe** ich spazieren *oder* [ich] **schaue** mir einen Film an.

Your example *Entweder du bist Teil der Lösung, oder du bist Teil des Problems* violates the fundamental definition of a V2 sentence because there would be two sentence parts in the *Vorfeld* (i.e. before the verb), making it actually an ungrammatical V3 sentence. (However, in spoken language there might be situations where native speaker move *entweder* to a *'Vor-Vorfeld'*, but this would be considered non-standard and mostly caused by psycholinguistical constraints).

The second sentence (after *oder*) remains unchanged, however, because *oder*, unlike *entweder*, is in fact a conjunction.

Comment: I don't see why *entweder du bist …* should be considered non-standard or unusual. Both [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/entweder) and [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/entweder) have example sentences of this kind: *entweder du strengst dich mehr an*, *entweder Sie kommen sofort*.

Comment: @DavidVogt I think it depends on the context: *Entweder du strengst dich mehr an oder wir sitzen morgen noch hier* -- fine. _*Entweder ich gehe spazieren oder schaue einen Film_ -- ungrammatical. *?Entweder du bist Teil der Lösung, oder du bist Teil des Problems* -- at least dubious from my point of view.